# How can I automatically start playing music upon entering of Konami code when visiting website?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could someone help me create some javascript to perform the following behavior.  Upon the entering of Konami Code while at a website (see:: http://files.www.gethifi.com/posts/konami/index.html for example), I want an mp3 to start playing in the background.  I want to do this without any external library, such as jQuery.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: 1) Accept answers. 2) What have you tried so far? "pls send teh codez" is generally not appreciated here.

Comment: 3) playing audio automatically on any website is generally considered offensive.

Comment: Not a fan of this "do my homework" style question, but in his defense, he wants music to play after cheat code is entered, not automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with the `onKeyUp` event, which gives you access to the [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.keyCode) property. You need a way to keep track of the keys pressed and you need to check each time to see if they match up to the Konami Code.

To play an MP3, take a look at the `object` tag and also see if you can add it to the DOM programmatically. Using all this information, it should be trivial for you to figure out how to write it all together.